# Is there a lightbox extension for Sphinx?

Tags: lightbox, python-sphinx

I have a static site in Sphinx and a ton of illustrations. Is there a simple way to integrate lightbox and generate thumbnails automatically?

```
 .. image:: picture.jpeg
    :lightbox: true
    :width: 200 px
    :alt: alternate text
    :align: right
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a dirty hack solution and paste it here because I'm not sure I want/have time to maintain it. It extends `Figure` class (to add text below) and abuses `download_reference` node. It also overrides in non-documented way the `app.add_node` method (which birkinfeld should have named `set_node`)

It generates a thumbnail and makes Sphinx put the original image in downloads.

You still need to add jQuery & [FancyBox](http://fancyapps.com) in your templates.

Enjoy

http://pastebin.com/pMhKnTkv

usage:

```
.. fancyimage:: img/exit_jam.jpg
    :fitwidth: 100
    :fitheight: 100
    :alt: cool
    :rel: tst
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the `sphinxcontrib-images` extension to your conf.py file:

```
extensions = [
      …
      'sphinxcontrib.images',
      …
]
```

Then use this setting to tell the extension to add lightbox to standard `.. image::` calls:

```
images_config = {
    'override_image_directive': True,
}
```

Or use the thumbnail option `.. thumbnail:: picture.png`

Be sure to install the extension first: `pip install sphinxcontrib-images`

For further information, see sphinxcontrib-images homepage at https://github.com/spinus/sphinxcontrib-images

Comment: https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/images - it was recently moved to sphinx-contrib

Answer (score 1):

No way I know of, though it might be a good candidate for creating a new extension.

Also, you might be able to do something similar just by modifying your template to include your favorite javascript lightbox-y image viewer, though that wouldn't handle generating thumbnails.